# Why is my d3.js selectAll + filter not filtering?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a parent **g** tag for each day which will contain a child **g** tag for the label.  The first item section of code produces the parents properly:

```
var content = d3.select(".content").attr("height", 1000).attr("width", 1000);

//create day groups
var days = content.selectAll("g").filter(".day")
        .data([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "day");
```

When I try to add a child **g** tag to each of them, though, it doesn't work:

```
// create the day headers
var day_labels = days.selectAll("g").filter(".day_label")    
        .data(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "day_label");
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: have you tried selecting them like so : d3.selectAll("days.g"); ? Can you put a basic JSFiddle together so we can try stuff out ?

Comment: You don't need to use filter() in this context. Filter would be used to apply properties based on the data.

Comment: I would normally do it like `days.selectAll("g.day_label")` to select only `g` elements with a `day_label` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your data binding. `selection.data()` expects an array to bind which works well in your first section creating the day groups. Remember, however, that `d3.selectAll()` will group the elements it found binding each item of your array to the corresponding group. The `selection.selectAll()` in your second section will retain this grouping and operate on the data previously bound per group. Using the identity function for data binding to the child nodes will therefore return the item of your array bound to the corresponding day node. For the first day label for example this will return the first item of your array which is just `0`. For `selection.data()` to work on the subselection, however, this should be an array.

Check the api reference for [further details](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) and an example:

> For example, you may bind a two-dimensional array to an initial
>   selection, and then bind the contained inner arrays to each
>   subselection. The values function in this case is the identity
>   function: it is invoked for each group of child elements, being passed
>   the data bound to the parent element, and returns this array of data.

To get this to work you may either:

1. Bind a two dimensional array, which is a bit clumsy in your case.

   ```
   var days = content.selectAll("g.day")
           .data([[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]])
           .enter()
               .append("g")
                   .attr("class", "day");
   ```

   This leaves the child section as is.
2. Combine the creation of both parent and child.

   ```
   var day_labels = content.selectAll("g.day")
                       .data([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
                       .enter()
                           .append("g")
                               .attr("class", "day")
                           .append("g")
                               .attr("class", "day_label");
   ```

Your choice will mostly depend on what you are about to do with the data bound.

By the way, have you seen Mike Bostock's article on ["How Selections Work"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)? It's definitely worth the time reading.